# SOLR Multivalue - set custom "space" between lines

Tags: solr, lucene, schema, proximity

Can I set some SOLR Multivalue field to have custom word space between them.

for example

```
"SomeMultiValueField":[
   "Word1",
   "Word2",
   "Word3"
]
```

How can I set in the schema that "distance" between each line is for example 20 words - so

```
 "Word1 Word2"~3
```

will yeild nothing 
but

```
 "Word1 Word2"~20
```

will contain result

Answer (score 0):

Use [the `positionIncrementGap` setting](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Field+Type+Definitions+and+Properties) on your field to set the distance between each token in a multivalued field.

```
<fieldType name="someMultiValueFieldType" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="20">
```

Comment: Sounds what I've been looking for :) - tried that, restarted SOLR and got many exceptions. will investigate it a bit and update here...